# Azure Search Service vs Full Text Search in latest Azure SQL Database instance?

Tags: azure, search, service, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

We need to implement search functionality on a table which might contain more than 100 000 records.

What is the best approach for the search when thinking about performance? Our product is a multi tenant with single database and search data may grow in future. What are the limitations of both searches?

Answer (score 0):

As always - it depends (e. g. which queries you perform, indexes etc...). In gernal if you only have simple queries, I would stick to Azure SQL Database. If you need more complex search features like geospatial search or ranking, you can try Azure Search.